# How can I add custom icons to the context menu?

Tags: windows, context-menu

Some programs like WinRAR have a checkbox in their options to show "Icons in context menu" but others don't.
I would like to add the own icons of the programs to the context menu.
Not only as an aesthetic detail, but also to locate them faster visually.
The programs in question are Link Shell Extension, Classic Shell, TeraCopy, ImDisk and wxMEdit.

Windows 8.1 Single Language 64-bit
6.3 (9600)

[image]

P.S. Sorry about my English, any correction is welcome.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say what version of Windows you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You control the area via registry:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers

You can edit (add/delete) keys there manually

Another options is to use one of the Context menu editors like any from the list [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors)

Comment: With this method he can choose what icons are shown, but he can't change the icons with custom ones, which is what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't customize that icons because the they are created using a different system of the classic one used in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.extension\shell\open\command` in which the information of which program is executed and extra data (like menu name and display icon) where stored directly in the registry, where you can modify it with the Registry Editor.

Those icons are created using a more advanced method in which each program register a .dll than handles all the stuff related to all the menu entries of that program, including the icon. New programs tend to use this system because is more flexible and provide more funcionality that the old one (for example this how WinRAR can have an entry for `Add to "filename.rar"` using the name of the selected file, with the old system it only could have the generic `Add to archive...`).

So the only option for customizing those icons would be if the offer an option like WinRAR do.